# VBA code that compare the current data + 10 days using Case statement

Tags: vba, excel, switch-statement

i have VBA code that allow user to enter a date AND COMPARE the entered date with the current in order to fill the cell in the appropriate color, i am using  the **Select Case Statement**.

i need to make the cell fill in red the user enter a date that is the current day + 10 days.

how t do it ?

## code

```
 Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim i As Integer
Dim objDate As Date


MsgBox (objDate)

For i = Range("C5000").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1 'Range upto 5000, chnge this as per your requirment'

    objDate = Date

    Select Case VBA.CDate(Cells(i, 3))

    Case IsEmpty(i)
         Cells(i, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = 0

    Case Is < VBA.Date()
        Cells(i, 3).Interior.Color = vbGreen

    Case Is = VBA.Date()
        Cells(i, 3).Interior.Color = vbYellow

    Case Is > VBA.Date()
        Cells(i, 3).Interior.Color = vbRed


  End Select
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Why do you have a `MsgBox` right after declaration? It won't contain any value. Dates and numbers are initialzed with 0. So, it'll just display 00:00:00. And what's the purpose of `objDate`. You don't use it anywhere in the code. It only adds to the overhead, as you're assigning it the same value inside your loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another way to accomplish that. Have the difference between the two dates as the test expression, and then check for each case (i.e., whether it's less than 0, equal to it, or if the difference is more than 10).

```
If IsEmpty(Cells(i, 3)) Then Exit Sub
Select Case (VBA.CDate(Cells(i, 3)) - VBA.Date())
    Case Is < 0
        Cells(i, 3).Interior.Color = vbGreen
    Case 0
        Cells(i, 3).Interior.Color = vbYellow
    Case Is > 10
        Cells(i, 3).Interior.Color = vbRed
    Case Else
        'Colour to be applied if the difference is between 1 and 10 (both inclusive)
End Select
```

Also, your test of `IsEmpty` will not work as you intend it to, because you're checking if the `i` (the counter) is empty or not. It'll always return `False`. Besides cells already have a `ColorIndex` of 0. So, unless your code has to check if previously non-empty cells have become empty, the `Cells(i, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = 0` part is unnecessary.

**Update:**

As a fun experiment, I tried it out to see how the results looked, and here's the screenshot:

[Macro in action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvMNc.jpg)

**PS:** Since the OP didn't mention the colour for when the difference was between 1 and 10, I coloured those cells black :-P